# Which algo is used on Intershop ecommerce platform?

Tags: password-encryption, intershop

Concerning an ecommerce migration, I need to extract customers account from an Intershop platform.
By the way, I suppose that password are currently stored encrypt (I hope), so to keep working current authentication process I need to reproduce password hashing algo.

Does someone can explain me which algo is use on Intershop platform, or transfert me some part of code which could help to reproduce it under php ?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

By default Intershop 7 uses PBKDF2.

Comment: This should be a comment (once you have [enough reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to add one). Please refer to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to learn how to earn reputation and therefore be able to comment. If you want to, you could turn it into a **full** answer by adding more detailed information and/or examples.

Answer (score 1):

PBKDF2 is the Intershop choice for default hashing algorithm.

The stored hash is calculated as follows:

```
<user_password_hash>=<S>PBKDF2(P, S, c, dkLen)
```

Here:

`user_password_hash`- the password hash as stored, hex encoded

`P`- the user password in plain text

`S`- salt - random 64 bits long salt

`c`- iteration count - 2000

`dkLen`- the length of the output - 256 bits

Please note that since the salt is a random 64 bit value, any password may have up to 2^64 valid and distinct hashes. Internally, PBKFD2 uses functions that are applied over and over again on the previously generated hashes. IS7 uses SHA-1 with HMAC for this purpose, applied 2000 times. The total storage requirements per password are:

```
salt = 64 bits
hash = 256 bits
---------------
total = 320 bit = 40 bytes
```

Since these bytes are stored hex-encoded, the total space is 80 bytes per password.